# Google Analytics API OAuth after clicking "Allow" cannot connect to local host

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to obtain an access token for Google Analytics API.

After creating a project in the developers console and granting acess to the Analytics API I reached the "create credentials" step and created new credentials for a web application.

On these credentials I set the Javascript origins to http://localhost:8080 and also http://localhost:5000. Then I set authorized redirect URIs to http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback as well as http://localhost:5000/oauth2callback.

Then, when I attempt to authorize I'm asked to enter my clientId and secret, which I do, then new browser tab opens and I'm asked to choose an account and then after that select "Allow".

[image]

Then, when I click "Allow" I'm taken to this page:
[image]

I also tried creating credentials for an application type of "other" but the exact same thing happened.

I've found numerous posts on stack overflow about this but none of the answers were able to solve my problem. Not sure which other info to provide. I even tried clearing history and using different browsers but with no success.

How can I give my application authorization to Google Analytics using OAuth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with localhost or your redirect uris or JavaScript origins.  The issue is that your code is not set up to handle the call back from the authentication server.  It would have helped if you had posted your code so it will be hard to know what the problem might be.

You should check the official example here [Hello analytics js tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello Analytics Reporting API V4</title>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="<REPLACE_WITH_CLIENT_ID>">
  <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello Analytics Reporting API V4</h1>

<!-- The Sign-in button. This will run `queryReports()` on success. -->
<p class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="queryReports"></p>

<!-- The API response will be printed here. -->
<textarea cols="80" rows="20" id="query-output"></textarea>

<script>
  // Replace with your view ID.
  var VIEW_ID = '<REPLACE_WITH_VIEW_ID>';

  // Query the API and print the results to the page.
  function queryReports() {
    gapi.client.request({
      path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
      root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        reportRequests: [
          {
            viewId: VIEW_ID,
            dateRanges: [
              {
                startDate: '7daysAgo',
                endDate: 'today'
              }
            ],
            metrics: [
              {
                expression: 'ga:sessions'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }).then(displayResults, console.error.bind(console));
  }

  function displayResults(response) {
    var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
    document.getElementById('query-output').value = formattedJson;
  }
</script>

<!-- Load the JavaScript API client and Sign-in library. -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```